# Import data from MongoDB to SQL Server

Tags: mongodb, ssis, sql-server-2012

I a developing a POC to import some data from MongoDB to MS SQL Server 2012. For e g. there are 5 collections n Mongo which need to be loaded to 5 tables in MS SQL Server tables. The data needs to be dumped as is.

What is the best approach to achieve this ? Wil any ETL Tool (SSIS) suffice or shall we have to write code in Node jS? Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use ZappySys' [SSIS PowerPack](https://zappysys.com/products/ssis-powerpack/), which includes MongoDB Source and Destination connections.